# Laravel Homestead saving images logic

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5.4, image-uploading, homestead

I am using homestead for my larval project. Currently I am trying to  an the image to inside my storage folder and the path in my database.

The function looks like this:

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $file = $request->file('category_avatar');
        $file->store('category_images');
        $location = storage_path('app/' . $file->store('category_images'));

        $category = new Category;
        $category->category_avatar = $location;
        $category->fill($data);
        if($category->save())
        {
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('message', 'Success');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('category.index')->with('error', 'Error.');
        }
    }
```

The image file successfully gets copied inside storage/app, but somehow to path which I save into my database is wrong:

Currently I get following path in my database:

```
/tmp/phpwOyIzA
```

If I `dd($location);` I get following output:

```
"/home/vagrant/code/myapp/storage/app/category_images/S4S5ml0XtsiBm6wLa4stQzTXZrEDzFf4egRljDjA.jpeg"
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line

```
$file->store('category_images');
```

Because the code below is enough

Comment: still does not work, it still save something like this /tmp/phpwOyIzA

Comment: weird. try `dd( $request->file('category_avatar')->store('category_images') )` what is the result? I'm using the same code and running as expected